# Can a Python + R file share a webdriver session between the languages?

Tags: python, r, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a scraper built in RSelenium. A number of tasks are more easily accomplished using Python, so I've set up a .Rmd file with access to R and Python code chunks.

The R-side of the scraper opens a website in Chrome, logs in, and accesses and scrapes various pages behind the login wall. (This is being done with permission of the website owners, who would rather users scrape the data ourselves than put together a downloadable.)

I also need to download files from these pages, a task which I keep trying in RSelenium but repeatedly come back to Python solutions.

I don't want to take the time to rewrite the code in Python, as it's fairly robust, but my attempts to use Python result in opening a new driver, which starts a new session no longer logged in. Is there a way to have Python code chunks access an existing driver / session being driven by RSelenium?

(I will open a separate question with my RSelenium download issues if this solution doesn't pan out.)

Comment: To my knowledge this is not supported. And selenium does not support interaction with already open browsers.

Comment: @Jortega Consider converting the comment into an answer so OP can accept it to reach to a logical conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, and with help from user Jortega, Selenium does not support interaction with already open browsers, and Python cannot access an existing session created via R.

My solution has been to rewrite the scraper using Python.